# How to use prepare to query with variables

Tags: wpdb

Trying to write a prepare statement that works.  This works:

```
$countthem = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_cmapg WHERE lang = 'yes'" );
```

This does NOT work:

```
$countthem = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_cmapg WHERE lang= %s", $lang ), 0, 0 
);
```

Also tried:

```
$countthem = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_cmapg WHERE lang LIKE %%%s%%", $lang ), 0, 0 
);
```

The contents of `$lang` is yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the single quotes back around the `%s`:

```
$countthem = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_cmapg WHERE lang='%s'", $lang) );
```

Comment: If the answer worked for you, the best thank you is to accept it (click the check mark under the vote arrows on the left), and once you have enough reputation, you can also vote up answers that are helpful.